# PHP XPATH couldn't find an element

Tags: php, html, arrays, xpath

This is the file.html

I'm trying to use xpath and php to loop through an element of the document and extract elements inside the segment and add it to an array and move to the next segment and extract the element to the next array.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="columns">
        <div width="90">
            <div class="item">
                <center>Yes
                    <br />
                    <a class="Link" href="https://google.com"><img  src="http://img.jpg" /></a>
                </center>
            </div>
            <p class="Icon">
                <a class="Link" href="https://google.com"><strong class="Title">Anchor Text</strong></a><br />
                <a class="secondLink"target="_blank">Anchor Text 1</a><br />
                <strong class="price"><a class="rice">Anchor Text 2</a></strong>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div width="90">
            <div class="item">
                <center>No
                    <br />
                    <a class="Link" href="https://bing.com"><img  src="http://img.jpg" /></a>
                </center>
            </div>
            <p class="Icon">
                <a class="Link" href="https://bing.com"><strong class="Title">Anchor Text 2</strong></a><br />
                <a class="secondLink"target="_blank">Anchor Text 2 1</a><br />
                <strong class="price"><a class="rice">Anchor Text 2 2</a></strong>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is the PHP CODE

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('file.html');
$doc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); 

if(!empty($html)){

  $doc->loadHTML($html);
  libxml_clear_errors();

  $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

  $scrape = $xpath->query("//div[@width='90']");
  if($scrape->length > 0){

  foreach($scrape as $row){

            $anames = array();
            $names = $xpath->query("//strong[@class='Title']", $row);

            foreach ($names as $name){
              $anames[] = $name->nodeValue;
            }




            $list[] = array('type' => $type, 'name' => $anames);
  }

print_r($list);
  }

}
?>
```

but I'm unable to extract the names from the strong tag. I get the following error

**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object **

This is the output:

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [type] => 
                Yes



        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => Anchor Text
                [1] => Anchor Text 2 
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [type] => 
                No



        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => Anchor Text
                [1] => Anchor Text 2 
            )

    )

)
```

I would like to be able to extract names and assign only 1 name to each array. As "Anchor Text" to the first array and "Anchor Text 2" to second array.

Comment: Where does `$anames` come from?

Comment: in which line does the error occur?

Comment: Look like a context problem. Can you try to replace "strong[@class='Title']" by  ".//strong[@class='Title']" ?

Comment: @FLX when i do that, i have to make an array to hold it. and it returns both the values in every array. PeeHaa, sorry i was testing it with array variable as $anames[]. I've now used the "//" xpath and I've modified the code to reflect the new output.

Comment: If i don't use an array($arrays), it returns "Anchor Text" on both parent arrays. how would i make it hold one value at a time.